# How to keep initialState before onChange with reactHookForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, react-hook-form

Language used : JS with REACT - REDUX TOOLKIT  (and in this case react hook form)

Here is the context: I have a form, when the user change something i get the change with redux-toolkit

Here is my problem : In react hook form, you can use register to update the state in a form with'onChange'. But here i'm using 'watch' (because of a radio button issue) and it's working.
So i watch and everytime someting is changing, I dispatch my data.
But on the first load, react hook form  watch and dispatch and i loose my initial state

Here a part of my code with the watch action

```
 const {
    register,
    watch, 
  } = useForm();

  const data = watch(); // when pass nothing as argument, you are watching everything

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(
      fetchData({

        name: data.name,
         //here i'm watching but loosing my initial state a the first render
      })
    );
    );
  }, [data, dispatch]);
```

Here my form with the register

```
  import React from 'react';
     
    
    export const Name = ({ register }) => {
      return (  
    <form> 
        <div >
          <label  >Enter your name </label>
          <input
            {...register('name')}
            type="text"
            name="name" 
          />
          <br />
        </div>
            </form>
      );
    };
```

here my slice with the initial state

```
const InfosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'infos',
  initialState: { 

    UserInfos: {
      name: 'Lydia',
    },
  
  },

  reducers: {
    fetchData: (state, action) => {
      state.UserInfos.name= action.payload?.name;
    },
  
  },
});
 

export const infosReducer = InfosSlice .reducer;

export const {
- 
  fetchData,
 
} = InfosSlice.actions;
```

In redux Devtools, in the frst load i see that i have the initial state

```
UserInfos: {
      name: 'Lydia',
    },
```

and then after the first watch with fetchData i only have

```
  UserInfos: { 
        },
```

How can i keep my initial state ?
I was thinking about something like "watch" but only changing when the initial value is changing

ps : I  have simplified my code for this question but in my project i have a form with multiple step, a lot of data etc.

Comment: Use reset function of react hook form to set the data on first load.

Comment: I will check, that's a good idea :)

Comment: Actually, i think it will not work because i have a lot of data in "fetch Data" (name was only for the example) and it's watching for every of them. So even if I reset on the first load, it will watch just after and dispatch  (and loosing my initial state)

Comment: I was maybe thinking of doing another useEffect without the watch for the data that i need to keep with initial state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved :

So for my case (i have multiple value to dispatch) I have removed the "name" in "fetchData" and I have created another function in my slice.

Then i've made the onChange directly in my input

```
    export const Name = ({ register }) => {
      return (  
    <form> 
        <div >
          <label  >Enter your name </label>
          <input
            {...register('name')}
            type="text"
            name="name" 
            onChange={(e) => dispatch(changeName(e.target.value)}
          />
          <br />
        </div>
            </form>
      );
    };
```

Comment: I would recommend not to dispatch values on onChange, as for example for 'Elodie', it will dispatch for every character and run for like 6 times and may impact the app performance.

Comment: But, some input need to get value from another this is why i dispatch every change..

For example my first input is "time" and the second is "price" then, the 3rd will be an addition of the first and the second to get "total price". Also, this is a multi step form, where the user can navigate from step 1 to 5 as he want so i can't have a "onSubmit" button, so i don't think there is another solution

Comment: also, actually, it dispatch my data 6 times at the first load because i dispatch with my useEffect and the "watch" parameters... Do you have any other solution to do a better way ?